# Angular-Firebase LogIn

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a set of data in firebase as: Username: 'username' and Password: 'password'

I have built an angular form with two textboxes. How do I compare the value entered by the user to the value stored in my database, and return an error if it does not match, on a button click? Please let me know, I must be missing something very basic.

Below is my code:
member-credentials.component.ts

```
       import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
       import {CredentialService } from '../../services/credential.service';

      import { Credential } from '../../models/credentials';

     @Component({
     selector: 'app-member-credentials',
     templateUrl: './member-credentials.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./member-credentials.component.css']
     })
     export class MemberCredentialsComponent implements OnInit {
     credentials: Credential[];
     Username ='';
     Password = '';
     public errorMsg = '';

       constructor(private credentialService: CredentialService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
       this.credentialService.getCredentials().subscribe(credentials =>{
       this.credentials=credentials;
      })
    }

  login(){
      //Where I want to implement the click.
   }

    }

   member-credentials.component.html
     <div *ngFor="let credential of credentials" class="container" >
        <div class="title">
            Welcome
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input type="text" class="validate" 
                   [(ngModel)]="credential.Username"  placeholder="User Name">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input type="password" class="validate" 
              [(ngModel)]="credential.Password"  placeholder="Password">
             </div>
            </div>

            <!--<span>{{errorMsg}}</span>-->
            <button (click)="login()" 
                class="btn waves-effect waves-light" 
                type="submit" name="action">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>    

   credential.service.ts
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, 
           AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

    import { Credential } from '../models/credentials';

   @Injectable()
 export class CredentialService {
   credentialCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Credential>;
   credentials: Observable<Credential[]>;

    constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.credentials = this.afs.collection('MemberDetails').valueChanges();
   }

    getCredentials(){
      return this.credentials;

   }

   }
```

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to compare password in Angular...whatever returned by the getCredentials() can be exposed easily, thus a security risk. What you can do is to post your login credential to the server and let the back-end do the logic/hashing; use Angular to only subscribe to the match result.

Comment: Hi,
I pushed the credential to the server. I could not find the way to use angular to compare the username and password. I searched for the way to use hashing, but could not succeed so far.

Comment: What I want to say is that Angular is pure front-end framework, so it's not meant to do back-end logic like authentication. Instead, since you are using Firebase as a wrapper, you can manage the logic, access the database, compare the hash, using whichever language (C++, JavaScript, Swift, Java, etc.) that works with Firebase, and then pass the result as a JSON response (for example, {"success": true, userName: "foo"}) that can be subscribed by Angular, and then let Angular handle the view.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have registered users and for that login to firebase console and activate authorization.

After that install angularfire2 module to use auth method which Will create same login data In firebase authentication console.

It looks a bit of too much work, but is simple. I suggest to check tutorials on youtube.

If you get stuck, message me i can explain bit of details because I know It can be frustrating for New people.

*Ps: auth method Will do comparing so you don't need to do it In front end.
Check this: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md*